# How to retrieve the result immediately without onClick listener?

Tags: java, android, textview

I would like to retrieve the calculation result of 2 `editText` values  into a `TextView` directly without pressing any buttons.

and also the result should updated directly when the values of editText changed.
So please how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use onkeyup event of editText elements

Comment: please check this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please provide the relevant part of code that you have done until now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnFocusChangeListener for retrieving the value of edit text after its focus get changed.

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if(hasFocus){
    //Retrieve edit text value and store it in variable.
}else {
//no focus
}
}
});
```

Get the values of both edit text, do your calculations with that and set it in textview like below

```
textview.setText("value");
```

Comment: Thank you for trying helping me , unfortunately it is not working and not updating.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  it should work if you want  to see any example you can look into http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener

Comment: There is no error, but it works only when click second time on editText so it retrieved the old value